# RxJava: Return results from inner nested loops

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to use RxJava to iterate over 2 arrays and accumulate the results in the inner loop and eventually return a `Single<Map>`.

Here is a snippet of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
private Map<String, Collection<String>> processData(List<Organization> organizations, List<User> users) {
    return Flowable.fromIterable(organizations) //
        .flatMapSingle(organization-> Flowable.fromIterable(users) //
            .filter(organization -> organization.exist(user)) //
            .toMultimap(organization, user))
        .blockingSingle();
}
```

I don't like the `blockSingle` call, is there a nicer way to handle this case?

**EDIT**

As suggested, I got rid of RxJava and use Java8 streams, as follow:

```
organizations.streams() //
        .map(organization-> users.stream()
            .filter(organization -> organization.exist(user))
            .collect(MultimapCollector.toMultimap(user::role, user::id)));
```

The thing I can't understand is how eventually to get the result as `Multimap<String,String>`, currently it returns as `Stream<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use *RxJava* for this task in the first place? There is no asynchronicity involved, so just use `.filter()`/`.map()`/`.flatMap()` from Java 8 (https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-filter-a-map-examples/).

Comment: and if I'm to do it using RxJava??

Comment: then blocking is ok because everything is synchronous anyway

Comment: I updated the question as you suggested, can you please take a look.